# Swing: checkbox spacing as compared to labels

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, label, spacing

How do you remove/reduce the spacing between checkboxes <strike>with MigLayout</strike>?

[image]

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class CheckboxSpacing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("checkbox spacing");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
        for (String verb : Arrays.asList("see","hear","speak"))
        {
            JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox(verb+" no evil");
            panel.add(cb, "wrap");
        }

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

---

**NOTE**: I'm wondering maybe if the MigLayout part of this question is a red herring. If I change my program to the following, I get these dialogs:

[image] [image]

You will note the difference in spacing between labels and checkboxes. How can I get rid of the excess spacing for checkboxes?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class CheckboxSpacing {
    enum WhichGUI { LABEL {
        @Override
        public Component createComponent(String text) {
            return new JLabel(text);
        }
    }, CHECKBOX {
        @Override
        public Component createComponent(String text) {
            return new JCheckBox(text);
        }
    };
        abstract public Component createComponent(String text); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doit(WhichGUI.LABEL);
        doit(WhichGUI.CHECKBOX);
    }
    private static void doit(WhichGUI which) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("spacing: "+which);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout(
                  "",  //layout
                  "[]", //column
                  "0"  //row
            ));
        for (String verb : Arrays.asList("see","hear","speak"))
        {
            Component c = which.createComponent(
                      verb+" no evil (Jabberwocky! Çgpq)");
            panel.add(c, "wrap 0");
        }

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in the preferred size of each component.

```
String text = "Hear no evil";
JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
System.out.println( label.getPreferredSize() );
System.out.println( label.getInsets() );

JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(text);
System.out.println( checkBox.getPreferredSize() );
System.out.println( checkBox.getInsets() );
```

A check box has non-zero insets. This would be from the border. So you should be able to either:

1. set the border of the check box to null
2. add an EmptyBorder to the label

Comment: thanks! I finally had time to try it, and setting the checkbox to null reduced the empty space. It looks like you need a little space for the focus rectangle to render properly, so I did `cb.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(1,1,1,1)));` and that seems to be a nice compromise.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this and they are well specified in [this document](http://www.miglayout.com/QuickStart.pdf).

You can specify the spacing either between the grid or the components. You probably want to do something like this:

```
     new MigLayout(
              "",  //layout
              "[]", //column
              "5"  //row
        );
```

And that should set the gaps. You will have to play with the numbers until you get what you want.

A second option (and I think you have more control this way is to do this:

```
  panel.add(cb, "wrap 0");
```

Where the 0 specifies the gap between rows.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Maybe it's not a miglayout thing, maybe it's a checkbox thing instead: if I use your suggestion to increase the row spacing to 100, I get more spacing. But if I change the row spacing to 0, I get more or less what I started with, and there's extra spacing I don't want.

Comment: If I use "wrap -3" then it looks about right, but there's something fishy about using a number less than 0.

Comment: @Jason S You may want to take a look at the component gap then. You have several options such as gaptop, gapleft etc to specify how far the component is away from the edge.